# Google Ads : tracking events

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-ad-manager

I'm little confused with Google services.
I want to track conversion events.

I've already configured the script like that :

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

My Google Tag Manager account is configured with deux services : Analytics and Ads

I've configured conversion event on Google Ads and I try to push it through Javascript calls, but maybe I'm wrong somewhere.

Here is my Javascript code :

```
gtag('send', <event_action>, {
  'event_category': <event_category>,
  'event_label': <event_label>,
  'value': <event_value
});
```

At the end of the day, I have no conversion on my dashboard on Google Ads.

Can someone helps with to figure out what's wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be `event` instead of `send`?

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

[reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events)

Answer (score 0):

Do you also include the gtag.js?

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
</script>
```

Comment: have you also tried to track the simpelst event `gtag('event', 'test');`
and maybe doublecheck your ID. I sometimes also use the wrong one.
Do you use only string as values?

Comment: @Dr.Z i think @shrys found the issue. You write `gtag('send', 'action')` instead of `gtag('event', 'action')`

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager and Google Ads have different base scripts and will not work together like this very well.

You can set up Google Ads Conversion Tracking in Google Tag Manager simply without additional code by going to tags click new then filling out the conversion ID and Label which can be found in the google ad conversion tools set up by click set up via tag manager.

Set the trigger in google tag manager and preview in Tag Manager to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a Chrome extension to help you test Google Tag Manager. [Get it here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en).

Comment: i've added the extension but I cannot see any events ? Should the plugin track them ?

Comment: Yes, the plugin will track them. You  should see your events under the Data Layer section. If you do not see them, then you probably have something wrong with firing the event. Unfortunately the Tag Assistant does not tell you what is wrong.